# Change footer content in magento

Tags: css, magento, footer

I'm new to editing the footer in magento. I want to use my footer instead of default and managed to remove QUICK LINKS and ACCOUNT according to [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/changing-the-footer-in-magento-theme), but  the 2 footer blocks showing in red block are placed vertically which I wish they are in horizontal and in the same format with the green block(colored title  and black links). Please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Footer Area, we are divided in two parts for fetching the information.

- One part is a static block which created within the Magento admin area (CMS > Static Block).
- The other part is held as .phtml / .php / .xml files within the design files.

  **XML files location:** app/design/frontend/PACKAGE_NAME/THEME_NAME/layout/page.xml , app/design/frontend/PACKAGE_NAME/THEME_NAME/layout/cms.xml

  Here you will find some footer references which which take you to .phtml files.

Eventually, you will be required to follow this two paths to get all the sections of footer sorted out and you will be able to edit everything at the end as I see it :)

Answer (score 0):

- Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
- Go to Developer on the  bottom left under ADVANCED
- Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
- Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.

Then refresh your frontend page. This will help you determine the phtml file that's arranging the layout of divs in your footer. Once found you can overwrite the file if it's a default one into your own theme's folder.

Comment: Thanks, after turning it on, I can see all phtml files associated with other blocks but the footer which is very werid, any idea?

Comment: Follow my answer you should find it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the bellow steps to edit footer :

Got to :

```
/app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/page/html
```

Inside `html` directory you have `footer.phtml` file. Download and edit.

If you have any query paste in comment.

Answer (score 0):

The links are available on **Admin menu -> CMS -> Static Block**

Here you choose **Footer Links** and *Add/Modified* your required links.